# Is this series conditionally convergent or absolutely convergent? $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{k+1}\sin\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

This series is not absolutely convergent because 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{k\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{\bigl|\left(-1\right)^{k+1}\sin\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)\bigr|}{\frac{1}{k}} & =\lim_{k\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{\bigl|\sin\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)\bigr|}{\frac{1}{k}}\\
 & =\lim_{k\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)}{\frac{1}{k}}\\
 & =1
\end{align*}
Since $
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}
$ is divergent, so is not absolutely convergent.

Is this conditionally convergent?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it converges conditionally, by the Leibniz criterion.

Comment: [Leibniz's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test#Formulation)

Comment: Is this correct? 
Because the derivative is $
\left(-1\right)\frac{1}{x^{2}}\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)
$, so when x from 1 and goes to positive infinity, the cos term is always positive. So $
\sin\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)
$ is monotone decreasing.

Comment: Sure, $\left(\sin\left(\frac1k\right)\right)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ is decreasing. Is that a problem? It's one of the hypothesis of the Leibniz criterion.

Comment: May I ask you that why this one is conditionally convergent? $
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{k+1}\frac{k^{k}}{\left(k+1\right)^{k+1}}
$

Comment: Again, by the Leibniz criterion.

Comment: Yes, to calculate the derivative of $
a_{k}=\frac{k^{k}}{\left(k+1\right)^{k+1}}
$. I was wondering that is there a simpler way to show it is monotone decreasing ?

Comment: Did I or did not answer your original question?